# Ignore Self-Signed certificate when building Url for SignalR javascript client

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-3.1, signalr-2

Is there a way to bypass a self-signed certificate when building the Url on signalR.HubConnectionBuilder() of JavaScript client?

I found this can be done and work perfectly in C# client with the following code

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("https://localhost:443/hub", (opts) =>
{
    opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
    {
        if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
            // bypass SSL certificate
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        return message;
    };
})
.Build();
```

But, I'm searching for exactly that in JavaScript client.

Comment: if you're using ASP.NET Core, you could do it without hard-coding in the source code. Run command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Comment: Trusting the dev certs doesn't work if you're using a node client.

Answer (score 2):

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0; // Disabling certificate verification
```

Adding the above line before attempting to make the connection solved it for me in NodeJS. This is for my developer setup.